# Discover the interface of a DVD drive (GT30L) on a very old HP notebook (Pavilion dv4-1620br)

Tags: laptop, dvd, hardware-detection

I'm trying to find out which interface to connect to the DVD drive, but it is very old, it must be from 2008-2010, does anyone have any ideas?
It is neither SATA nor IDE.

[Photo: Inside the notebook (interface in)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0B8.jpg)

[Photo: Device info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvWzM.jpg)

[Photo: The strange interface (interface out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fieks.jpg)

Comment: Not enough pins for IDE. Chances are that the connector panel on that DVD drive can be unscrewed and removed and you'll probably find a SATA drive.

Comment: That is a proprietary HP interface, see if the back panel will come off the drive to see if it is an adapter that can be removed.